# How to separate rows of dataframe based on dynamic conditions using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Weird issue I can't seem to wrap my head around and I know there's a better way to look at it, I'm just stuck. I need to grab chunks of this data based on the type. 1 through 4 go together in a sort of set, so I would want for example, rows 0 through 8, then 9 on. Each set would be entered as an entry in a database.

```
     num          date   type      signed
0   294981  2015-05-01      1        None
1   299888  2015-05-22      2  2015-05-28
2   299891  2015-05-22      2  2015-05-28
3   316150  2015-07-14      3  2015-07-23
4   336930  2015-10-13      3  2015-10-16
5   357536  2015-12-29      3  2015-12-29
6   379224  2016-03-14      3  2016-03-18
7   403862  2016-06-10      3  2016-06-10
8   414282  2016-07-26      4  2016-08-03
9   439184  2016-11-10      1  2016-11-14
10  448972  2016-12-12      2  2016-12-14
11  464306  2017-02-02      3  2017-02-06
```

Thing is this data isn't static, there are sets with that might have 10 rows of type 3's, no 1's or 4's. So if I have below:

```
     num          date   type      signed
0   294981  2015-05-01      2        None
1   299888  2015-05-22      2  2015-05-28
2   299891  2015-05-22      2  2015-05-28
3   316150  2015-07-14      3  2015-07-23
4   336930  2015-10-13      3  2015-10-16
5   357536  2015-12-29      3  2015-12-29
6   379224  2016-03-14      1  2016-03-18
7   403862  2016-06-10      3  2016-06-10
8   414282  2016-07-26      3  2016-08-03
9   439184  2016-11-10      4  2016-11-14
10  448972  2016-12-12      1  2016-12-14
11  464306  2017-02-02      2  2017-02-06
```

I need to get out:

```
     num          date   type      signed
0   294981  2015-05-01      2        None
1   299888  2015-05-22      2  2015-05-28
2   299891  2015-05-22      2  2015-05-28
3   316150  2015-07-14      3  2015-07-23
4   336930  2015-10-13      3  2015-10-16
5   357536  2015-12-29      3  2015-12-29

     num          date   type      signed
6   379224  2016-03-14      1  2016-03-18
7   403862  2016-06-10      3  2016-06-10
8   414282  2016-07-26      3  2016-08-03
9   439184  2016-11-10      4  2016-11-14

     num          date   type      signed
10  448972  2016-12-12      1  2016-12-14
11  464306  2017-02-02      2  2017-02-06
```

Unfortunately there's no other way to group this data other than that stupid type value. I'm competent with Pandas and can't find a way to do it, nor can I think of anything else to use for this without telling Python *exactly* which values to grab, which of course I don't know without looking at the data.

Help is so appreciated! (btw, I said 'dynamic conditions' in the title because the type column values are not 1-4, or 2-4 or 1-3 or anything that I can set. It will vary depending on the data generated at the time)

Comment: Can you phrase your question more clearly? I have read it thrice and I'm still not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: @jimmy-c I'm sorry about that! I added a bit so you can see how the data needs to be grouped. It needs to be in groups of 1-4 (with no changes to the date order). Once i have the data, I'll take the first, last and middle values for something else. I need to show the beginning, end and middle phases of each 1-4 set. I hope that makes sense, it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to start a group over after the type is lower then the type in the previous row, this code should work:

```
class Group():
    start = 0
    last_type = 0
    def four_group(self,x):
        if x < Group.last_type:
            Group.start +=1
        groupNum = Group.start
        Group.last_type = x
        return groupNum


df =  pd.read_csv("chart.csv")
zzz = Group()
df['TempGroup'] = df.type.apply(lambda x:zzz.four_group(x))
```

Using your second dataframe:

```
     num          date   type      signed
0   294981  2015-05-01      2        None
1   299888  2015-05-22      2  2015-05-28
2   299891  2015-05-22      2  2015-05-28
3   316150  2015-07-14      3  2015-07-23
4   336930  2015-10-13      3  2015-10-16
5   357536  2015-12-29      3  2015-12-29
6   379224  2016-03-14      1  2016-03-18
7   403862  2016-06-10      3  2016-06-10
8   414282  2016-07-26      3  2016-08-03
9   439184  2016-11-10      4  2016-11-14
10  448972  2016-12-12      1  2016-12-14
11  464306  2017-02-02      2  2017-02-06
```

The code returns:

```
       num        date  type      signed  TempGroup
0   294981    5/1/2015     2        None          0
1   299888   5/22/2015     2   5/28/2015          0
2   299891   5/22/2015     2   5/28/2015          0
3   316150   7/14/2015     3   7/23/2015          0
4   336930  10/13/2015     3  10/16/2015          0
5   357536  12/29/2015     3  12/29/2015          0
6   379224   3/14/2016     1   3/18/2016          1
7   403862   6/10/2016     3   6/10/2016          1
8   414282   7/26/2016     3    8/3/2016          1
9   439184  11/10/2016     4  11/14/2016          1
10  448972  12/12/2016     1  12/14/2016          2
11  464306    2/2/2017     2    2/6/2017          2
```

You can then split up the data frame based on TempGroup, then drop the TempGroup column.

Edit: mixed up dataframes

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you'll be able to tell the sets apart because the type of the next one will be less than the earlier one.

You can add an extra temporary column that adds serial numbers of separated dataframes. Something like this :

```
def separate_df(t):
   res = pd.Series()
   previous_df_no = 0
   for (index, value) in t.iteritems():
       if index==0:
           res.set_value(index,0)
       else:
           if value<t.loc[index-1]:
               previous_df_no += 1
           res.set_value(index,previous_df_no)
   return res
df['temp'] = separate_df(df.type)
```

Then you can tell what dataframe each row belongs to using the serial numbers and delete the temporary row after separating.

Comment: Priya thanks so much! I decided to go with the class-based answer but still using similar logic.

Answer (score 0):

As an observation I see your "type" looks like it is grouping by years.  If so, something like this may work for you:

`getYear = lambda x: x.year
data.year = data.date.apply(getYear)
myGroup = data.groupby(year)`

Comment: Shoot sorry if it looks that way, it's definitely a coincidence of this sample. All 1-4 sets span multiple years.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with different conditions. Might be useful to someone else. I wanted to separate rows on the condition of my "tvshow" column being the number 21. So, every time I find 21 in the column, I reset the df['TempGroup'] count. 
Summary of dataset:

```
tvshow,time,duration
15,9.4,7.1
0,10.1,0.6
3,10.7,0.5
```

Code:

```
class Group():
    start = 0
    last_type = 0
    Group.start = 0
    def four_group(self,x):
        if x == 21:
            Group.start = 0
        else: Group.start += 1
        groupNum = Group.start
        Group.last_type = x
        return groupNum
# Read from .csv
df = pd.read_csv('/home/dataset.csv')
grp = Group()
df['TempGroup'] = df.tvshow.apply(lambda x:grp.four_group(x))
```